# Tiny VM based on immutable data structures?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, immutability, vm-implementation

Is there any "tiny" VM (for any programming language) where the main data structures visible to the user (lists, arrays, maps, sets, etc.) are immutable as in Clojure or Haskell?

By "tiny" I mean a VM where implementation simplicity, brevity and portability are key points: think Lua or TinyScheme.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it aligns with your "key points", but you might take a look at [Pixie](https://github.com/pixie-lang/pixie).  Pixie implements a VM in RPython.  One of its claims is a small footprint of just over 10MB for the compiled VM + standard libs.  The language is a lisp based (loosely) on Clojure.  It appears to maintain Clojure's policy of immutable by default, and definitely has implementations of Clojure's persistent datatypes.

Comment: Thanks! Seems quite a bit heavier than Lua et.al. but this may be the best contender. It definitely seems to have similar "lightweight" ideals.

Answer (score 1):

## Owl Lisp

A "purely functional Scheme". The VM is 1600 lines of C.

> Owl Lisp is a purely functional dialect of Scheme. It is based on the
>   applicable subset of R7RS standard, extending it mainly with threads
>   and data structures necessary for purely functional operation. Owl can
>   be used on most UNIX-like systems, such as Linux, BSDs and OS X.
>   Programs are typically compiled via C to standalone binaries, so Owl
>   isn't needed to run programs written in it.
>
> Owl project originally got started both as an attempt to extend R5RS
>   Scheme with some necessary features, such as threads and modules, and
>   as an experiment on how being purely functional influences the runtime
>   and use of an applicative order purely functional language. While
>   things have been added to Scheme, Owl tries to keep the core language
>   as simple as possible.
>
> Implementationwise the goal was to get a small portable system which
>   could be used to ship programs easily. This is currently accomplished
>   by using a small register-based virtual machine, which can be extended
>   with program-specific instructions to reduce interpretive overhead.

- https://haltp.org/n/owl
- https://github.com/aoh/owl-lisp

## ClojureC

> Compiler for the Clojure programming language that targets C
>   as a backend. It is based on ClojureScript ... Before you can run
>   anything make sure you have GLib 2 and the Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage
>   collector installed.

- https://github.com/schani/clojurec

## TinyClojure

> TinyClojure is a project to build a small, easily embeddable version
>   of Clojure/ClojureScript in portable C++. In many ways it is my
>   attempt to create a Clojure equivalent of TinyScheme.
>
> ...
>
> ClojureC is good, but the build process is complex, and
>   there are external library dependencies ... The focus with TinyClojure's development is to make it the easiest way
>   to embed Clojure within any application. Tiny Clojure consists of one
>   header file, one source file, no external dependencies, and the
>   extension and embedding interface is as simple as it is possible to
>   be.

- https://github.com/WillDetlor/TinyClojure/